# Save C-Style array values using gmock

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have the following expectation on one of my objects:

```
EXPECT_CALL(usbMock, Write(_, expectedBufferLength));
```

Where the '_' argument is the buffer being passed to Write function on the usbMock.

I need to get the values inside that buffer, so that I can run my own array comparison function (ElementsAreArray and ElementsAre doesn't work for me, because I needed custom output message with exact contents of expected/actual array, and also my arrays are more than 10 bytes long);

In any case, I got very close to solving my problem with the following:

```
byte* actualBuffer;
EXPECT_CALL(usbMock, Write(_, expectedBufferLength)).WillOnce(SaveArg<0>(&actualBuffer));
```

The problem is that this is an integration test, and the buffer pointed to by actualBuffer gets released, by the time I'm able to act on it.

My question is, how can I save the contents of the actualBuffer for later inspection, instead of just getting a pointer to it.

Comment: Probably `EXPECT_CALL` is some preprocessor macro. So read its documentation (or comment), study its definition, look into the preprocessed form (with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) you can get it using `g++ -C -E`....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found myself in the same situation a couple times, and I have two potential strategies to offer:

- You can define a custom matcher (see `MATCHER_Px` macros)
- You can use `Invoke` and perform the actions you need in the callback

In your case, it will depend on whether you know what to expect at the point where the code is invoked: if you already know, then you can define a matcher that takes the expected array in parameter, otherwise if you need to save it you can use the callback in `Invoke` to perform a deep copy.

---

Some code samples:

```
// Invoke
EXPECT_CALL(usbMock, Write(_, expectedBufferLength))
        .WillOnce(Invoke([expectedBuffer](byte* actualBuffer, size_t length) {
            // Substitute for your matching logic
            for (size_t i = 0; i != length; ++i) {
                EXPECT_EQ(actualBuffer[i], expectedBuffer[i]);
            }
        });
```

And with the matchers:

```
MATCHER_P2(ByteBufferMatcher, buffer, length, "") {
    return std::equal(arg, arg + length, buffer);
}

// Usage
EXPECT_CALL(usbMock,
    Write(ByteBufferMatcher(expectedBuffer, expectedLength), expectedLength));
```

Note that the latter makes it more difficult to supply a custom error message.

Comment: I actually did try both of those approaches.  The problem with Invoke is that it only passes 'actualBuffer' as an argument, and there is no way to add an 'expectedBuffer' argument.  The Matcher_Px on the other hand, lets me pass only a single argument, so I can pass in 'expectedBuffer', but not its size.  I'm guessing the only solution is creating my own class/struct that contains both the pointer to the buffer, and its size?  Unless you have a better suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: @Eternal21: I edited to include some example code, which should make it easier to understand what I meant.

Comment: Thanks for the code samples, that's one thing I hate about gmock documentation - it's too cryptic to understand without samples.  One question - what's the purpose of square brackets around [expectedBuffer] - I can't find anything about it in gmock documentation?

Comment: @Eternal21: Yes, I've struggled with the gmock docs because of this more than once... and then I go and do the same ;) The square brackets are there to demark the [capture clause of a lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). This is a C++11 feature, and there are probably other tutorials out there if the cppreference link is too cryptic but I don't know any off the top of my head...

Answer (score 1):

You can do it that way:

```
MATCHER_P(CompareCustomArray, expectedArray, "") {
    CustomArray* customArray = std::get<0>(arg);
    return ((*customArray) == (*expectedArray));
}

CustomArray actualBuffer("Expected Buffer Value");

EXPECT_CALL(usbMock, Write(CompareCustomArray(&actualBuffer), 
                           expectedBufferLength));
```

Here we created specific matcher that compares of two `CustomArray`s and it "passes" if they are equal.